# I am trying to build a dictionary, but need to keep changing values

Tags: python, dictionary

for string(abcabcabc) <abc * 3>,

dict[0] = a, then dict[0] = ab, dict[0] = abc,

oh a repeat, next line
dict[1] = a, etc.

```
test_case1 = 'abcabcabcabc'
test_case2 = 'abccbaabccba'


def case_test(s):
    case_test_dict = {}
    i = 0
    p = 'z'
    for x in list(s):
        if ((x != case_test_dict) & (x != p))|((x == case_test_dict) & (x != p)):
            case_test_dict[i]=(x) # <--- problem
            p = x
        elif p==x:
            i +=1
    print(case_test_dict)

print(case_test(test_case1), '\n', case_test(test_case2))
```

Basically, it'll output the last letter entry. I can't continue until I get that point nailed down.

edit:
Found an entirely alternate method

```
def case_test(s):
    case_test_list=[]
    for x in list(s):
        case_test_list.append(x)
        len_multi = len(s) / len(case_test_list)
        str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in case_test_list)

        if (int(len_multi) * str1) == s:
            return len_multi
        
print(case_test(test_case1), '\n', case_test(test_case2))
```

It outputs exactly the right answer I wanted.

edit2: Forgot to add what that output is.

The output is '4.0, 2.0' a count of the number of times the pattern is repeated.

Comment: `&` and `|` are bitwise operation. I think you meant to use the logical operators `&&` and `||`

Comment: use `and`, `or` instead of `&`, `|`. You can also use `print()` to see what you get in variables and comparitions - `print( x, case_test_dict, x != case_test_dict )`, etc.